# Styles.Render does not load CSS files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When attempting to use the Bundles in a MVC5 application.  The CSS files fail to load, when I inspect the source I see the following reference in the HTML :

```
<link href="/Content/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Why isn't this working as I expect? I have tried using different virtual paths, but that doesnt seem to work.

My BundleConfig.cs file:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Navi
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my _Layout.cshtml I have the following:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My issue here was I needed to add the following to the global.asax file:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

This also required that I include: `using System.Web.Optimization;`

Answer (score 7):

You should not use a bundle name that is the path to a folder which already exists in the solution.
e.g `("~/styles/css")`

Answer (score 0):

Add BundleConfig file and include  @using System.Web.Optimization reference in _Layout.chtml file like this

[image]